# Headline Capitalization

Tags: java, text-processing, unix, utility, dos

## Background

Developers write JIRA tickets; developers do not style the ticket items consistently. We'd like to present the ticket summaries to clients, but with a consistent format.

## Problem

We're using FreeMarker Pre-Processor (fmpp), which supports title case and first letter caps, but these simple functions lose information (e.g., "BCServices" becomes "Bcservices" and "iPhone" becomes "Iphone").

## Examples

There is JavaScript code that does a great job of making the summaries uniform:

- https://titlecaseconverter.com/
- http://individed.com/code/to-title-case/

This formats the following summaries as expected:

- On iPhone the Transcript Extends Outside of Screen Frame
- PEAR And GNA Report Performance
- BCMailPlusFTPClient sends document without document ID
- JWebUnit: non-PEN orders main.xhtml meta refresh tag issue

## Requirements

We're looking for something that can be run from the command line (as part of a batch program) that doesn't require a huge binary. Ideally:

```
@echo off
headline < "On iPhone the Transcript Extends Outside of Screen Frame" > case.txt
set /P title=<case.txt
```

Pie-in-the-sky would allow for issuing different styles on the command line:

```
@echo off
headline --style=CMS < "On iPhone the Transcript Extends Outside of Screen Frame" > case.txt
set /P title=<case.txt
```

We're not looking for NodeJS modules, Ruby code, Go programs, Perl scripts, and similar. Plain JavaScript is okay (not ideal as it requires something like Rhino).

## Question

What Java, C, DOS batch, small Windows binary, free/unlimited REST API, or Unix shell utility allows processing of sentences to be "headline case" as per standard manual styles?

## Addendum

It is overkill to include a JavaScript engine (Rhino) to run a regular expression. Although the my answer works as expected (including a Java class that performs the task), alternative suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Rhino

Since Java was included in the requirements:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Download_Rhino
- https://github.com/gouch/to-title-case/blob/master/to-title-case.js

## Example

Run:

```
java -cp rhino\lib\rhino.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main ^^
-e "load( 'to-title-case.js' ); ^^
print(""BCMailPlusFTPClient sends document without document ID"".toHeadlineCase())"
```

Output:

> BCMailPlusFTPClient Sends Document Without Document ID